# Paypal: How my server can authorize some payment made by mobile client

Tags: security, paypal, token

I want to let my customers on mobile application to be able to make payments using Pypal .. so far so good!

Now I want the mobile application to send to the backend server a payment confirmation with the amount payed, if I just made the mobile application to send those information to the backend just like that without any type of authenticity, that will be very hackable and totally insecure, is there some kind of token that Paypal passes to the client, and then to the my backend server, that the server can authorize the payment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the official documentation, steps are listed by details:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/